# Dynamic amount of images printed on JPanel

Tags: java, image, background-image, paint

I have a stickynote png image and I want to basically at runtime, grab the data in the database and then print out as many images onto the JPanel as there are records in the database, then print text over each png so there is a sticky note type of look and feel.

My problem is when I loop through and try to create images, do I need a separate image object reference for each one or can I reuse the same image object in the loop?  This code would be in paintComponent in a class extending JPanel.  I feel like I am thinking about this all wrong...

```
for example for(i=0;i<recordCount; i++
{
   Image image = new ImageIcon("mysticky.png").getImage
}
```

My problem is that I think that this will overwrite each new image put on the Jpanel.  What is the best way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: The best way (probably) is to alter the images, drop them into a JLabel, and add the JLabels to a JPanel (possibly with a GridLayout or BoxLayout).  Overriding paintComponent() is not necessary.

Comment: But then how do I name them somethign different each time because there could be potentially a variable amount of variables/image and JLabels necessary, so how do I name those dynamically?  I am really having a hard time with this concept of basically a random number of variables created at runtime.  I think I am not conceptualizing the solution.  Can you please give a more concrete code example?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need just one image.

Use:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("mysticky.png");

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
    for(ImagePanelImage nextim : backgroundImages) {
      g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

You may want to search the web for the concept of 'background image' in java.